# Data frame subsecting loop

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset, text-alignment

I have a dataframe composed by several paired columns. So, for example, the first column is a list of names and the second column contains numeric values quantifying the variables of the first column. In the third column I have again a list of names and the fourth column is numeric and quantifies variables of the third column and so on.

I now want to automatically subset the first two columns to make a separate dataframe and the third-fourth columns to make a second dataframe. The final aim is to align the rows by name.

For example, from dataframe a

```
names_a<-c("a","b","c","d")
values_a<-c(1,2,3,4)
names_b<-c("a","b","e","f")
values_b<-c(5,6,7,8)
a<-as.data.frame(cbind(names_a,values_a,names_b,values_b))
```

I would obtain a dataframe containing names_a and values_a and another dataframe containing names_b and values_b, then aligning them to have dataframe a1:

```
names_a1<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
values_a1<-c(1,2,3,4,0,0)
values_b1<-c(5,6,0,0,7,8)
a1<-as.data.frame(cbind(names_a1,values_a1,values_b1))
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I can help for the first Part of your request. Please see how to create the separated data frames.

```
names_a<-c("a","b","c","d")
values_a<-c(1,2,3,4)
names_b<-c("a","b","e","f")
values_b<-c(5,6,7,8)
a<-as.data.frame(cbind(names_a,values_a,names_b,values_b))

#When you subset a data frame you focus on observations (rows), not on the variables (columns). You can create 2 new data frames out of the existing one.


#df contain 3+4 Variable
a34 <- data.frame(cbind(as.vector(a$names_b),as.vector(a$values_b)))
colnames(a34) <-c("names_b","values_b")

#then "subset" a (in fact you create a new one and replace it)
a <- data.frame(cbind(as.vector(a$names_a),as.vector(a$values_a)))
colnames(a) <-c("names_a","values_a")
```

This result in:

```
> a
  names_a values_a
1       a        1
2       b        2
3       c        3
4       d        4
> a34
  names_b values_b
1       a        5
2       b        6
3       e        7
4       f        8
```